# How to use python and TextBlob to get list of incorrectly spelled words in my nltk corpus

Tags: python, spell-checking, textblob

I want to check the spelling of an nltk corpus I created

When i pass raw text from an nltk corpus through textblob's spellcheck() I get the following error `Object has no len()` and the code section below.

Is there a way to get the list of incorrect spellings detected in my text without having them corrected first

```
site-packages\textblob\_text.py in suggest(self, w)
   1386         if len(self) == 0:
   1387             self.load()
-> 1388         if len(w) == 1:
   1389             return [(w, 1.0)] # I
   1390         if w in PUNCTUATION:

TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears my corpus wasn't configured correctly to iterate through the base files
I needed 
`PlaintextCorpusReader(completeFolder, '.*txt')` instead of
`PlaintextCorpusReader(completeFolder, '.txt')`

the give away was Corpus.fileids() didn't return anything until I fixed the code